# Merge two model arrays in a route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a controller handling a list of models. These models are of two different types (e.g. `Message` and `Comment`). In order to use an `ArrayController` I would have to merge both lists into one. Is there a way to do this ?

Class-based polymorphism, [as proposed in this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-class-centered-polymorphism/3457), would solve my problem, but they are not likely to be implemented soon.

In my current solution, I use an `ObjectController` reveiving both `comments` and `messages`. I then merge them using a computed property:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Em.Object.create({
      comments: this.store.find('comment'),
      messages: this.store.find('message'),
    });
  },
});

App.SomeIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  merged: Em.computed.union('messages', 'comments'),
});
```

It works, but I don't benefit from all the niceties of an `ArrayController` (like `sortProperties` for example).

What I would like to do is something like:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var comments = this.store.find('comment');
    var messages = this.store.find('message');
    return merge(comments, messages);
  },
});
```

where `merge` returns something similar to what is returned by `this.store.find('model')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @bmeyers' answer, and after exploring ember-data's source a little bit, I came up with a solution that is reusable and not too terrible. It is probably not optimal, but it does the work.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  findMultiple: function (types) {
    var self = this;
    var recordsByType = types.map(function (type) {
      return self.find(type);
    });
    return self.mergeArrayPromises(recordsByType);
  },

  mergeArrayPromises: function (promises) {
    var promise = Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(arrays) {
      var mergedArray = Ember.A();
      arrays.forEach(function (records) {
        mergedArray.pushObjects(records.toArray());
      });
      return mergedArray;
    });

    return DS.PromiseArray.create({
      promise: promise,
    });
  },
});


App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.findMultiple(['comment', 'message']);
  },
});
```

Comment: awesome! I'll try it out in my own app. Thanks dude.  Are you finding you need to keep refetching the array or does it auto update?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't think it will auto update. You will have to try ;)

Answer (score 7):

I asked a similar question recently, here is how I solved the issue.

```
App.SomeIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['some field'],
  sortAscending: false, // false for descending
  merged: function() {
    var comments = this.get('comment') || [], // This gets wherever you've stored the comments array
        messages = this.get('message') || [];// This gets wherever you've stored the messages array
    var stream = Ember.A();

    stream.pushObjects(comments.toArray());
    stream.pushObjects(messages.toArray());

    return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
        content: stream,
        sortProperties: this.sortProperties,
        sortAscending: this.sortAscending
    });
  }.property('messages.@each', 'comments.@each')
});
```

Hope this works for you as well.  Just an FYI, for my example, my controller is actually one that is rendered, so I do not set up the model for it in the route.  I simply have properties on my controller, lets say, `commments` and `messages` that constantly updated themselves as RecordArrays.

So for your example you may need to observe `.property('model.messages.@each', 'model.comments.@each')`

Comment: No problem, I think it would be good to create some sort of mixin that can merge record arrays, or some other addon to the framework, if you come across anything better let me know, I am going to work on creating some so that not all this code is necessary every time.

Comment: I added an answer that may also be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.  I stumbled upon this a while back and your question reminded me

https://gist.github.com/sebastianseilund/6096696

Comment: Unfortunately I tried implementing this with the newest versions of ember and Emer-data and it no longer worked  :(